# Play top artist songs with Deezer ios sdk

Tags: ios, deezer

How can I play the top Artist songs on Deezer iOS SDK?

I got the DZRArtist object by this way.

```
        [DZRArtist  objectWithIdentifier:@"469353"
                          requestManager:self.manager
                                callback:^(DZRArtist *artist, NSError *error) {


                                }];
```

The DZRArtist object is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I never used Deezer SDK before but I made my searches and found you can get the artist ID from your URL then put it https://api.deezer.com/artist/{ARTIST ID}/top?limit=50&output=xml

```
NSString *artistID //get your ID
NSString *songsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.deezer.com/artist/%@/top?limit=50",artistID];
```

now you have your URL you just need to make your request :)